# Onlick event not triggering which contains blur function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a `form` and on click on an `input`, I'm adding classes to that `input`'s wrapped `div`.

To do this, I've made use of `blur` and executing my function on `click`. However, on some cases (very rarely) it will work (and add the class). But majority of the time, it doesn't perform the `click` action (because the `console.log("click")` doesn't appear).

My thinking is that maybe the browser is conflicting between the `blur` and `click`. I have also tried changing `click` to `focus`, but still the same results.

Demo:

```js
$(function() {

  var input_field = $("form .input-wrapper input");
  $("form .input-wrapper").addClass("noData");


  function checkInputHasValue() {
    $(input_field).on('blur', function(e) {
      var value = $(this).val();
      if (value) {
        $(this).parent().closest(".input-wrapper").removeClass("hasData noData").addClass("hasData");
      } else {
        $(this).parent().closest(".input-wrapper").removeClass("hasData noData").addClass("noData");
      }
    });
  }

  $(input_field).click(function() {
    checkInputHasValue();
    console.log("click");
  });


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've done some modification in your code .

```
function checkInputHasValue(e) {
  var value = $(e).val()
      if (value) {
        $(e).parent().closest(".input-wrapper").removeClass("hasData noData").addClass("hasData");
      } else {
        $(e).parent().closest(".input-wrapper").removeClass("hasData noData").addClass("noData");
      }
    
  }
  $(document).on('blur',input_field, function(e) {
    checkInputHasValue($(this));
});


  $(document).on("click",input_field,function() {
    checkInputHasValue($(this));
    console.log("click");
  });
```

Comment: With this, the `console.log("click");` executes and I can see it on `console`, but none of the classes get added to the fields.

Comment: i've done some modification in your code

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid conflits between events, you would separate the events and your value check. In your code, the blur event may occur multiple times.

The following code seems ok, as far as I can tell ^^

```js
$(function() {

  var input_field = $("form .input-wrapper input");
  $("form .input-wrapper").addClass("noData");

  function checkInputHasValue(el) {
    let target = $(el).closest(".input-wrapper");
    var value = $(el).val();
    $(target).removeClass("hasData noData");
    $(target).addClass(value.length == 0 ? "noData" : "hasData");
    
    console.log("hasData ?", $(target).hasClass("hasData"));
  }

  $(input_field).on("click", function() {
    console.log("click");
    checkInputHasValue(this);
  });

  $(input_field).on("blur", function() {
    checkInputHasValue(this);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <input>
  </div>
</form>
```